# ruby inject with conditional in block?

Tags: ruby, inject

doing the first Project Euler question: summing the multiples of 3 and 5 between 1 and 1000, I came up with this (pretty simple)

```
sum = 0
1.upto(999) { |i| sum += i if 0 == i%3 || 0 ==  i%5 }
sum
```

but I thought this would work but it doesn't, can someone show me what I'm doing wrong, or why it doesn't work?

```
1.upto(999).inject(0) { |sum, i| sum + i if 0 == i%3 || 0 ==  i%5 }
```

thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`inject` passes the result of the block through to the next iteration as the first argument. Your block will return `nil` when your `if` statement is false, which then gets passed back in as `sum`.

To get the correct answer, the block should return the current sum when it's false:

```
1.upto(999).inject(0) { |sum, i| (0 == i%3 || 0 ==  i%5) ? sum + i : sum }
```

Answer (score 3):

Complementary answer: if you're about to tackle Euler problems you should start to build your own extensions of reusable code. In this case, the first extension would be `Enumerable#sum`:

```
module Enumerable
  def sum
    inject(0, :+)
  end
end
```

And now you can write a solution that separates the condition of the summatory (you can read it out loud and it makes sense, that's typical of functional/declarative style):

```
1.upto(999).select { |x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.sum
```

You could even push it one step further and create `Fixnum#divisible_by?` so you can write:

```
1.upto(999).select { |x| x.divisible_by?(3) || x.divisible_by?(5) }.sum
```

More: here it's not a problem, but later on strict implementations (those using arrays) will require too much memory. Try then with [laziness](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4890):

```
require 'lazy'
1.upto(999).lazy.select { |x| x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0 }.sum
```

Comment: This is great info.  I'm going to follow it as a few questions in and I see the usefulness of the advice.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
1.upto(999).inject(0) { |sum, i| sum += i if 0 == i%3 || 0 ==  i%5; sum }
```

Would also work (note the `+=`).

Comment: thanks for the alt answer.  This is closer to my initial setup and so I'd probably do it this way (more readable to me), I accepted the first answer because of the explanation of the error - the 'aha!' moment to me helped

Answer (score 2):

Or, use `&` proc which addresses self.

```
(1..999).select{|x| x%3==0||x%5==0}.inject &:+
```

Answer (score 2):

`(1..999).to_a.keep_if{|d| d%3 == 0 || d%5 == 0}.reduce(:+)` for completeness.